# Is the repeated use of units in sentence okay?

Tags: grammar, convention

Consider the following sentence:

> Also on Fig. 2, is the estimated price of a pizza at five locations along the highway (z=0, 4, 6 and 8km).

or

> Also on Fig. 2, is the estimated price of a pizza at five locations along the highway (z=0km, 4km, 6km and 8km).

or

> Also on Fig. 2, is the estimated price of a pizza at five locations along the highway (z=0km, z=4km, z=6km and z=8km).

which is a proper way to present units?

Comment: In any case, add a thin space between the number and the unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer will depend on your style guide.  A Style guide that I am familiar with, the American Physical Society Style manual, says,

> Do not repeat units of measure in a series of 2 or more items, in a
>   range of values, with a ± symbol, with the combinations "from...to"
>   and "between...and", with versus (vs.), or with a multiplication (×)
>   symbol. However, when other words intervene, units can be repeated if
>   necessary for clarity.

So your first option looks right to me.

Comment: This was exactly the situation and answer that I was looking for.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage.